# Login security of web application

Tags: .net, security, ssl

I have a basic login (index.asp send a form to login.asp to verify the credentials) and I recently discovery that I can make POSTs (XMLHTTP with classic ASP) from another domain to my login.asp.

I want to avoid this operations and my question is:
If I install the SSL Certificate on my site, can I control which domains can make POSTs to my domain?

Can I solve my problem with .NET forms?

Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL won't change who can POST data to your forms (after all, you don't know the identity of the computers who post data to your web server beforehand, do you?)

The typical way to protect against this is for each request to `index.asp`:

1. Generate a random integer on the server side, and store it in Application state on the server.
2. Write this integer into a `hidden` form field on your login form
3. Reject any requests to `login.asp` without this hidden field set correctly for the user's session

Now, this won't prevent remote hosts from programatically accessing `login.asp`, but it will force them to go through `index.asp` each time, as if they were a real user.

If your concern is that a remote host might try to brute-force your login system, you should look at rate-limiting accesses to `login.asp` from a given host, or timing-out a user ID after, say, 5 failed login attempts.

Comment: See [OWASP's guidance](https://owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) for other ways to protect against Cross Site Request Forgeries (CSRF)

Comment: Big +1 @Michael for the OWASP link. There's some really strong content on there for this kind of problem.